# Is it possible to create a QueueProcessingFargateService with read-only root filesystem with cdk?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-fargate

*AWS Foundational Security Best Practices v1.0.0* has a high risk check; *[ECS.5] ECS containers should be limited to read-only access to root filesystems*. The remediation explains how to change this in the console. However, I haven't found a way to do this for a QueueProcessingFargateService using CDK.

If a QueueProcessingFargateService could be created without an image, this could have been solved by calling add_container on the task definition, but image is mandatory so that doesn't work.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a QueueProcessingFargateService with read-only root filesystem and if so, how?

(I use CDK in Python, but a solution in any other CDK language will be just as useful)

Comment: You mention it's possible with add_container, what is the option you'd pass in during that call?
You may need to use an escape hatch to get it done. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html)

Comment: If there is no image, add_container of the task definition has a parameter readonly_root_filesystem that can be set to True - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateTaskDefinition.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.FargateTaskDefinition

Comment: @MatthewBonig the escape hatch works. I have got confirmation from AWS Support elsewhere that it is not (yet) possible with CDK directly. If you add your comment about the escape hatch as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this isn't a property directly supported on the construct you'll need to use escape hatches to set it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite cloudformation properties using [`Aspects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/aspects.html). For example:

```js
import { Aspects } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

const fargateService = new ecsPatterns.QueueProcessingFargateService(this, 'FargateService', {
// ...
});

Aspects.of(fargateService).add({
    visit: (node) => {
        if (node instanceof ecs.CfnTaskDefinition) {
            node.addPropertyOverride('ContainerDefinitions.0.ReadonlyRootFilesystem', true);
        }
    }
});
```