# Using the CDK ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct is it possible to specify a read-only root filesystem?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I'm trying to set the continer definition readonlyRootFilesystem=true but I'm not sure it's exposed in this construct.

I similary question here: [Is it possible to create a QueueProcessingFargateService with read-only root filesystem with cdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73399299/76066)

But we're using the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService, can't see how we'd do this with Escape hatches.

Comment: Yes, it would work the same as with `QueueProcessingFargateService`, you'll have to use escape hatches.

Comment: @gshpychka Yeah but I can't see how? I can get hold of the Container (maybe?) but the parameter is readonly..!

Comment: Check the docs on escape hatches, they should mention overriding parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a QueueProcessingFargateService with read-only root filesystem with cdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399299/is-it-possible-to-create-a-queueprocessingfargateservice-with-read-only-root-fil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for escape hatches. Define the Task Definition with the `taskDefinition` prop instead of `taskImageOptions`.  You must provide [one or the other](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html#taskdefinition), but not both.

The `taskDefinition` prop accepts a [FargateTaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.FargateTaskDefinition.html) construct, on which you can set `readonlyRootFilesystem: true`.  The `taskImageOptions` is a convenience prop that creates a `FargateTaskDefinition` for you under the hood, but with fewer options.

```js
const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDefinition", {});

taskDefinition.addContainer("sample", {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),
    readonlyRootFilesystem: true,
});

new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(stack, "Service", {
    // ...
    taskDefinition,
}
```

In other words, the constraints mentioned in the linked question [no longer apply](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/4213).

Answer (score 1):

The above works. However, I prefer the usage of [`Aspects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/aspects.html)

```js
import { Aspects } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

const fargateService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'FargateService', {
// ...
});

Aspects.of(fargateService).add({
    visit: (node) => {
        if (node instanceof ecs.CfnTaskDefinition) {
            node.addPropertyOverride('ContainerDefinitions.0.ReadonlyRootFilesystem', true);
        }
    }
});
```